# How do I get real-time information about newly created tokens on Solana?

Tags: spl-token, deploy

I want to receive information about newly created tokens on the Solana blockchain with minimal latency. What are some ways to do this?

So that I get information about a freshly created token after, say, 30 seconds in the format:

Address, supply, image, creator's address

The programming language is not so important, it's the method itself that matters. Thank you in advance!

I've tried playing around with things like BitQuerry and GetBlock, but haven't gotten to the bottom of it. Maybe I haven't given it enough time, or maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction

Comment: Please did you find solution to this? Can you please share with me, I keep buying rugs. Help

Comment: yes, please did you find solution to this? thanks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Helius will be your friend here. I am not sure how much latency u are looking for. Two approaches:
1 - set up a free webhook on helius, to pipe blocks, and parse block contents. u should also be able to filter the webhook stuff to return only specific actions back, so cutting down to just new token would help.

2 - write a cript that refreshes every 30 seconds, and checks the ;metadata program/guithub repo gor any new tokens , and outputs the result

your buggest problem is that these new tokens will belong to the token program, and fetching all the accounts (GPA) is not a good way to run these things.

If you are looking to use this fro something serious, then i suggest reaching out the helius team to explore their webhook solution for this.

Comment: Yes, I've discovered Helius webhooks, using self-created filter and it works

Comment: Hey Andrew, can you please provide an example or some info how did you do that? would be super helpful!

Comment: Hi, can you please show a tutorial example of your custom filter? thanks @AndrewSwift

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient method for receiving real-time updates on account and transaction changes is to operate a read-only validator equipped with a Geyser plugin. This setup allows for direct streaming of events to your services. However, maintaining a server for this purpose can be costly, and a validator can only support a single plugin.

In response to these limitations, several RPC providers have begun offering access to Geyser through various methods. For instance, Helius offers account webhook services, while Triton's DragonMouth feature enables the streaming of Geyser events to backend systems via gRPC protocol.

https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins

https://docs.triton.one/project-yellowstone/dragons-mouth-grpc-subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

I believe [dexscreener](https://dexscreener.com/?rankBy=pairAge&order=desc&chainIds=solana&minLiq=30&maxFdv=100000&maxAge=1&max24HTxns=200)(you can filter the information based on the query params) provides information on newly created tokens.

[Birdeye](https://birdeye.so/new-pairs?chain=solana) and [Bonkbot](https://t.me/bonkbot_bot)'s alerts channel also provides information on newly created listings, albeit slightly different that what you asked for.

Birdeye also has a [token-list endpoint](https://docs.birdeye.so/reference/get_public-tokenlist) that you might find useful.